# Install reddit on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, reddit

I'm getting the following error:

> install-reddit.sh: line 79: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or
>   directory

```
 cat /etc/issue
```

gives me

> CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

I know the script is for ubuntu: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/reddit-install-script-for-Ubuntu but I was wondering if there is a way to make the script run on centOS? When I try to install normally it fails

Comment: You would have to look the script over carefully and evaluate everything it does for Ubuntu-specific details and convert anything that is specific to an appropriate equivalent for CentOS. That may be simple and easy but most likely is going to involve quite a lot of work and changes but I haven't looked at the script beyond seeing that it is 800+ lines long.

Comment: The Red Hat family have a `/etc/redhat-release` instead of `/etc/lsb-release` to show some version info. But like Etan says, hard to know what else isn’t suited.

Comment: @MicahElliott ah ok I was afraid that might be the case. I was hopeful there was a known solution. Oh well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did not find a solution to running the easy install from reddit. Instead I used vagrant to create a virtual Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) which with a little fiddling worked fine for me.

The one issue is that you have to preallocate space for it (unlike if it were local (clearly)). I had to increase the size 4x to get it working for me.